# return value type hinting for container of basetype

Tags: python, type-hinting

I define AnimalBase for base class for animals.
And then I define Cat, Dog class that inherits AnimalBase.
How to annotate return value of some functions that return a list including cats and dogs.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, List
from abc import ABC

class AnimalBase(ABC):
    pass


Animal = TypeVar("Animal", bound=AnimalBase)


class Cat(AnimalBase):
    pass


class Dog(AnimalBase):
    pass


def get_animals(cls) -> List[Animal]:
    return [Cat(), Dog()]
```

I got the following error.

```
t.py:21: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "Cat"; expected "Animal"
t.py:21: error: List item 1 has incompatible type "Dog"; expected "Animal"
```

Comment: Why not just `List[AnimalBase]`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey `AnimalBase` is an abstract class, so I want to distinguish them. `Animal` is a concrete type like `Dog` and `Cat`.